# Translate and transform plane geometry based on corner coordinates

Tags: three.js

I have a plane mesh with divisions and I want to specify the coordinates that each of the corners should be positioned.  Moving and updating the mesh vertices achieves what I'm trying to do, so long as the plane only has no internal segments.  If internal segments are added then I have more vertices than I can manually place, so these need to automatically fall in line with the transformation of the outer edges.

My initial thought here was that I could create a geometry with only four vertices, reposition them, and then increase the number of segments on my plane, apparently, this isn't something that Three.js supports, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this sort of transformation is expressible as a single matrix that you could then just apply to your plane mesh. I think you really do need to calculate the coordinates of each vertex of the subdivided plane manually.

There are different ways to do this calculation. [Bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is this case seems to do the job. Here's how you do it. If you have four points A, B, C, D, then for each internal points, its position can be found as the weighted average of (the weighted average of A and B, and the weighted average of C and D). The weights for the averages come from the index of the subdivision vertex in one direction (say, X) for the inner averages and in the other direction (say, Y) for the outer average. Your indexes run from 0 up to the number of subdivisions in that direction (inclusive), the weight should be from 0 to 1, so the `weight = index / number of subdivisions`.

[image: Example courtesy of @prisoner849]

Comment: Stefan, thank you for the insight.  I'll try my hand at implementing this as a solution and let you know how I fare.

Comment: I think you're absolutely correct in your suggestion.  I ended up finding an alternate solution that eliminated my need to do this sort of complicated translation.  Thank you very much for the suggestion though.

Comment: Interesting question and answer. Upvoted both (cheers!). My approach is here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/311z5ceo/)

Comment: @Dig_Dig_Dig could you show your solution, if it's not a secret. please )

Comment: @prisoner849 Great implementation! That's exactly what bilinear interpolation looks like. It would be cool to see the effect in 3D, that is, to also interpolate the Z coordinate.

Comment: @StefanDragnev Added OrbitContorls. Now it's possible to rotate the scene and drag the corners of the plane.

Comment: Curvilicious :)

Comment: Gorgeous!  @prisoner849 My end goal was to create a scene with georeferenced 3D terrain.  We ended up loading in an array of XYZ (lat, lon, elevation) coordinates that we converted using [proj4js] (http://proj4js.org/), then explicitly telling each point of our mesh where in space to position itself.

Comment: I have to say, I'm a big fan of this solution!  This would let us use our original method of a displacement map to set the height of our vertices.  The big benefit of this for us is that we would be able to easily change the level of detail in our tiles without having to mathematically drop points and update the geometry.

Comment: @Dig_Dig_Dig ;) It was kind of an exercise for my brain. If it helps, feel free to use it ))

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks!  It'll be fun to deconstruct and implement in our framework.  I'll post a fiddle here if anything interesting comes of it.